# Student's t-test for the excel sheet using python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, statistics

I have an excel sheet with data for 60 years for 50 Regions like follows:

**Year R1 R2 R3 .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. R50**

1951 66 45 22 .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. 20

1952 54 .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. 15

..

..

2010 51 33 .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. 45

I want to do the t-test over the data for two intervals 1951-1980 and 1981-2010. and want to store the t and p-value of each region in an excel or csv file. How can I do for whole data?
The link of the input datafile is
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1d3zpgUuGxTm-ncJQp-3sek9T6LKptY8a/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=100218359178484671666&rtpof=true&sd=true

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_excel("t-test_Data.xlsx")
l=list()
for i in df.columns[1:]:
    l.append(pd.DataFrame({i:ttest_ind(df[df.Year < 1981][i],df[df.Year >= 
1981][i])}))
d=pd.concat(l,axis=1)
d.index=["statistic","p_value"]
d.to_excel("t_test_statistic.xlsx")
```

Comment: It has an error as :
 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Year'

Comment: Run this first     df = df.reset_index()

Comment: Thank you.. I remove the df.year to df.index and then it worked.